# DOMNodeList::getAttribute is undefined

Tags: php, html, dom, html-table

Im tryin to run this code  but php throws: **Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::getAttribute() in path/to/feature-manager.php**

This file contains html

```html
//features.php

<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="media/artwork_icon_512.png" id="feature-icon1">
  <h4>Feature 1</h4>
    </div>
</div><!---->
    
    
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature">
 <img class="img-fluid" src="media/dress_flat_icon-512.png" id="feature-icon2">
  <h4>Feature 2</h4>
    </div>
</div><!---->
    
   
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="feature">
  <img class="img-fluid" src="media/users-512.png" id="feature-icon3">
  <h4>Feature 3</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

then i call it to this file

```html
//feature-manager.php

$read=file_get_contents('../include/features.php');
$features = explode('<!---->', $read);

$doc= new DOMDocument();
foreach ($features as $feature) {
 
$doc->loadHTML($feature);
$img = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img"); 
 $imgsrc = $img->getAttribute('src');
 
echo $imgsrc;
```

Clearly I want to get the src attrib from it but somehow doesnt recognize getAttribute()

Answer (score 1):

You have to loop through the results of getElementsByTagName()

This function returns a DomNodeList, getAttribute belongs to the DOMElement

```html
//feature-manager.php

$read=file_get_contents('../include/features.php');
$features = explode('<!---->', $read);

$doc= new DOMDocument();
foreach ($features as $feature) {
 
    $doc->loadHTML($feature);
    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName("img"); 
    foreach($images as $img){

     $imgsrc = $img->getAttribute('src');
     echo $imgsrc;
    }
}
```